# Why is my network interface named enp0s25 instead of eth0?

Tags: networking

A lot of my scripts stopped working after installing Ubuntu 15.10 and I have trouble remembering this new name as I was used to ethx and wlanx for years. Is there a reason for this change? Do I have to get used to this or can I just rename it and go back to good old eth0?

```
$ ifconfig

enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 77:5a:5e:a6:86:d5  
      inet addr:192.168.31.239  Bcast:192.168.31.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::725a:b6ff:fea6:86d7/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4833 errors:1332 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:666
      TX packets:5589 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3266446 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:1046654 (1.0 MB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:d3500000-d3520000
```

Comment: see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/679117/predict-network-interfaces-names-in-wily/679141#679141) which also has a further link to more details.

Comment: Ooooooooooooooor fix your scripts once and for all and remove the reference (and change it for a command to determine the  device name) ;-) (here are some pointers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/396837/detecting-the-name-of-a-network-device-in-bash )

Comment: @Rinzwind That is great idea.

Comment: @Mike my boss (= lead coder) always agrees with me on that too but then he always uses hard coded paths and devices... and I scold him again and again ;)

Comment: Dupe of this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134483/why-is-my-ethernet-interface-called-enp0s10-instead-of-eth0

Answer (score 140, accepted):

This is known as [Predictable Network Interface naming](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) and is part of [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), to which Ubuntu has been transitioning as of version 15.04.

Basic idea is that unlike previous *nix naming scheme where probing for hardware occurs in no particular order and may change between reboots, here interface name depends on physical location of hardware and can be predicted/guessed [by looking at `lspci` or `lshw` output](https://askubuntu.com/a/654928/295286). Conversely we can guess information about it's physical position in the pci system. In your case that would be pci bus 0, slot 2. According to [the freedesktop.org article](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/), there actually are 3 ways how interface name is assigned: based on BIOS/Firmware for onboard cards, based on PCI information, and based on MAC address of the interface. [Refer here for other examples](https://major.io/2015/08/21/understanding-systemds-predictable-network-device-names/).

According to [the freedesktop.org page](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) one of the reasons for switching to predictable naming is that classic  naming convention can lead to software security risks in multi-interface systems when devices are added and removed at boot. Also, according to [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704361/why-is-my-network-interface-named-enp0s25-instead-of-eth0/704364#comment1302830_704364) by [Sam Hanes](https://askubuntu.com/users/113000/sam-hanes), "On a big server with many Ethernet ports it's invaluable: you can immediately tell which interface goes to which port and adding or removing hardware doesn't change the names of other ports."

See [How to rename network interface in 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/689501/295286) in case you decide to revert back to the other version of naming.

Comment: I see little irony in word "predictable" :), thank you for the pointers.

Comment: "predictable", yeah, sure. I have ethernet disconnections after upgrade to 15.10 (clean install, old /home). Why break APIs and conventions? Now I have to figured out what is failing. I'm very upset with this :(

Comment: failing is predictable i guess ;)

Comment: eh, tell that to the `systemd` developers, guys.

Comment: Predictable Naming isn't particularly useful on desktop systems with only one interface, and in that case it's kind of obnoxious. On a big server with many Ethernet ports it's invaluable: you can immediately tell which interface goes to which port and adding or removing hardware doesn't change the names of other ports. That's the case it's designed for.

Comment: @Anwar when you fail to predict, it's predictable you'll fail ;)

Comment: I don't get any advantage from this change so far.

Comment: Wow, that really broke a lot of software.  Nice move systemd.  You make so many new friends!

Comment: Actually predictable naming breaks every now and then on modern systems when you insert a new PCI/PCIE network adapter. On one of my mainboards (X58 Extreme IIRC) this resulted in all the NIC names changing.

Comment: switching from the ethx, wlanx naming scheme to the enpxsx and wlpxsx scheme is a bit difficult. specially in the first days and while returning back from using other distros that still use the old naming schemes, like `kali`. but after a while I got the hang of it and now I become frustrated with switching back to the old name in `kali`. The hardest challenge is restructuring my scripts to use the names I screen scraped from `ifconfig` instead of the hardcoded names 
 like eth0 or wlan0 - much thanks to the creator of `cut` and `regexe` - the mathematicians, not the ones that coded'em.

Comment: can this wonderful new naming scheme be disabled and the old one be used?

Comment: @lurscher see https://serverfault.com/a/741212/363611

Comment: This has a downside with desktop systems with build-in ethernet adapters. I was an Ubuntu noob back then, I installed 16.04 and it ran fine. However, when I added a new USB PCIE card, I noticed I lost ethernet connectivity. The reason was that built-in ethernet adapter's PCIE index changed (and its enpsX0 name changed accordingly at boot), but its name in `/etc/network/interfaces` remained the same. So I went to the store to buy a new adapter and found out it never fixed the issue.

Comment: @JimmyFalcon Common users of desktop systems don't edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and swapping adapters don't affect them. If you edit the file manually, yoiu should know that when you change an adapter you need to do the change.

Comment: Pilot6, swapping PCIE cards does affect users of desktop systems with built-in ethernet controllers. Whenever a PCIE card added or removed (USB controller, GPU, etc), the motherboard "moves" the built-in ethernet controller to another PCIE slot, enpsXX boot up name changes accordingly, whereas /etc/network/interfaces name does not. Thus, machine boots to non-working connectivity state. To fix it, user must edit the /etc/network/interfaces file manually to reflect the change. I can confirm the problem exists on AMD 970 chipset motherboards.

Comment: This wonderful new invention has grinded my computer into a standstill more than the equally wonderful nvidia dkms driver. why is this enabled by default on desktop systems ?

Comment: Suddenly, my server refused to come online, and it turns out that the network interface previously predictably known as enp179f0s0 is now even more predictably known as enp180f0s0.  No idea how that happened, both ethernets are soldered on the mainboard, so I'm pretty sure I haven't moved them about.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW the freedesktop.org PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames file references a source file's comments as canonical but that file has been altered to remove the comments - see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/12518.

Comment: The new canonical reference is [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the quick fix I use on Debian and RHEL based systems**

#Edit /etc/grub/default

**Step 1. ) Add this to the line below "net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"**

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"

**Step 2.) Update GRUB**

This depends on your OS.

**Debian based Ubuntu/Mint:**

update-grub

**Centos/RHEL**

grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

Source: http://realtechtalk.com/Linux_How_To_Change_NIC_Name_to_eth0_instead_of_enps33_or_enp0s25-2303-articles