# wlan0 is missing?

Tags: wireless

Or maybe not, when I use iwconfig, instead of wlan0 I get wlx00....etc for my wireless card. Is this normal?

Comment: Probably for essentially the same reasons as [Why is my network interface named enp0s25 instead of eth0?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/704361/why-is-my-network-interface-named-enp0s25-instead-of-eth0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called Predictable Network Interface Names, and it's actually been in place since Ubuntu 15.10.

The gist of the problem that they were trying to solve was that network devices names (ie:wlan0) would sometimes change for what seemed no reason. Add another network device and the names would change.

With the new naming convention, theoretically the names will stay the same, no matter how many network devices you actually have. In your case, wlx00... means wireless interface, and the number is more than likely the MAC address.

I personally don't like the new naming convention, partly because simple terminal commands now require longer/stranger names than wlan0.

Comment: Yes this is annoying however I can work around this with `nmtui` but that only works interactively.

Comment: Just adding `net.ifnames=0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in the `/etc/default/grub` then updating grub made it so my host is back to the old way.  I too did not like that change.  Glad this OS allows me to change things like this.