# Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS - issues with update and interfaces

Tags: 16.04, networking, apt, server, ethernet

I will describe my problem:

1) I installed ubuntu server 16.04.3 LTS on an HP Proliant DL380 G7 server using a bootable USB stick.

2) As soon as the installation is finished, I wanted to update the system with the command: `sudo apt-get update` but an error appeared to me:

```
E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read
```

-> the contents of the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is as follows:

```
Ubuntu Update Rest
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates

deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-update
```

3) I have an ethernet cable connects from my server to the router.

4) My network interface is a bit weird, I do not understand why it is of this form enp13s0f0 and not eth0 !!!

So if someone has an answer, it will help me a lot because I am blocked :(

Comment: re: 4) Please see [this question about interface naming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704361/why-is-my-network-interface-named-enp0s25-instead-of-eth0)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: re: 2) Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` seems to have been modified, one trivial thing that is missing is the component, it should at least look like this :

```
Ubuntu Update Rest
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main

deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-update main
```

And about your network interface name, `eth0` is no more in use, since this name can change from one boot to anoter, see [predictable network interface name](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). But if you really want it to be named `eth0`, this old behavior can be restored like [described here](https://serverfault.com/a/741212/430340).

Comment: Thank you very much @pim for the answer, but the problem persists. the error is as follows :

Err: 1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
        Temporary failure resolving 'from.archive.ubuntu.com'

Err: 2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-update InRelease
        Temporary failure resolving 'from.archive.ubuntu.com'

Comment: Now either you've got no internet, either there are other problems in your file. I think you don't have the original file anymore?

Comment: Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/RandomReaper/d625d2f149f23b4228944678d25d898c/raw/53eb78a0c3038663ab9e2d41b6c96d1055ace32c/sources.list feel free to try it. If it works, you can still replace the ch.archive... by de.archive....

Comment: No I do not have internet either I am connected with an ethernet cable from the server to the router but the internet does not work.

I will try to replace my file /etc/apt/sources.list but the problem is that I can not copy to paste on the screen of my desktop since I am on a laptop and I write to you from my personal computer. I have to write it with my hand?

Comment: If you don't have internet, there is no need trying to install software form it. First of all fix your internet connection.

Comment: the problem is that i have an address enp13s0f0 which has a @ static 192.168.2.161 and l @ of my router which is connected to the server through an ethernet network cable is 192.168.2.160.

I put a @ network 192.168.2.0 and the gateway 192.168.2.160 which is the @ of the router.

Is this correct?

Comment: Please if you can help me to configure my internet connection because i'm new at ubuntu server and i want to learn more about this practices.

Comment: tell me what information you need.

Comment: Have a look at how other host are configured on the network, then copy/adjust the configuration for your machine. Otherwise open another question for the network configuration