# Ubuntu 18.04 - How to reload interface

Tags: 18.04, interface

I'm trying to reload /etc/network/intefaces file to remove the current ens160 interface, but nothing I've found seems to do the trick.

What command is needed on 18.04 to do that?

Comment: How did you configure the interface in the first place?
Did you try `ifdown ens160`?

Comment: By default 18.04 doesn't use `/etc/network/interfaces` or `ifdown` or `ifup`. It uses netplan.

Comment: I'm working on an upgrade from 16, this isn't a clean install. I had hardcoded a static ip on 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the root of my problem :

I wasn't using netplan. Since I upgraded from 16.04, it seems the upgrade didn't configure the relation between netplan and NetworkManager properly. This is probably caused by the hardcoded static ip I had added.

The solution I used is as follows :

1. Using NetworkManager, create a wired connection to replicate the static ip I want.
2. Remove all mentions of the hardcoded interface in the file /etc/network/interfaces
3. Reboot ( I have yet to find how to skip this step, but whatever )
4. Create the missing file /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

5. `sudo nmcli con up 'Wired connection'`
6. I executed the command `sudo netplan apply`, but I'm not certain if it's required or not

From there on, I can modify my connection then just down and up it to apply my modifications.

Comment: Installing 16.04, then configuring a static IP, and finally upgrading to 18.04 is a perfectly valid thing to do. If that causes breakage it's a bug. I happen to have a 14.04 system with static IPs that I probably soon will need to upgrade to 18.04. So I may have to come back to this issue myself in the not so distant future.

Answer (score 0):

Been busy myself with trouble and yesterday i remembered to see a similar question here which you may wish to read up on.

[Why is my network interface named enp0s25 instead of eth0?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704361/why-is-my-network-interface-named-enp0s25-instead-of-eth0)

Maybe you can find your solution in that thread